# Implementing stochastic forward passes in part of a neural network in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

my problem is the following:

I am working on an object detection problem and would like to use [dropout during test time to obtain a distribution of outputs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02142). The object [detection network](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet) consists of a training model and a prediction model, which wraps around the training model. I would like to perform several stochastic forward passes using the training model and combine these e.g. by averaging the predictions in the prediction wrapper. Is there a way of doing this in a keras model instead of requiring an intermediate processing step using numpy?
Note that this question is not about [how to enable dropout during test time](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5357)

```python
def prediction_wrapper(model):
    # Example code.
    # Arguments
    #     model: the training model
    regression     = model.outputs[0]
    classification = model.outputs[1]

    predictions     =   # TODO: perform several stochastic forward passes (dropout during train and test time) here

    avg_predictions =   # TODO: combine predictions here, e.g. by computing the mean

    outputs =           # TODO: do some processing on avg_predictions 

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=outputs, name=name)
```

I use keras with a tensorflow backend.
I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand, you're trying to average the weight updates for a single sample while Dropout is enabled. Since dropout is random, you would get different weight updates for the same sample.

If this understanding is correct, then you could create a batch by duplicating the same sample. Here I am assuming that the Dropout is different for each sample in a batch. Since, backpropagation averages the weight updates anyway, you would get your desired behavior.

If that does not work, then you could write a custom [loss function](https://keras.io/losses/) and train with a batch-size of one. You could update a global counter inside your custom loss function and return non-zero loss only when you've averaged them the way you want it. I don't know if this would work, it's just an idea.

Comment: the idea is to use standard dropout during training, so there is no need for averaging the weight updates. Then at test time, dropout is still used and I perform several forward passes to obtain a sample of different outputs (where the randomness is caused by different dropout masks). The idea of copying the input might work, will look into it. Thanks for your response.